# Mixed regular and copied properties in ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Using [property iteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#property-iteration) we can multiply properties in ARM resource. But how can I mix these copied properties with others that are typed explicitly?
What I expect might look like this snippet (of course it's incorrect because "probes" property is duplicated).

```
"probes": [
{
    "name": "FirstProbe",
    "properties": {
    "intervalInSeconds": 5,
    "numberOfProbes": 2,
    "port": 123,
    "protocol": "Tcp"
    }
},
{
    "name": "SecondProbe",
    "properties": {
    "intervalInSeconds": 5,
    "numberOfProbes": 2,
    "port": 456,
    "protocol": "Tcp"
    }
}
],
"copy": [
{
    "name": "probes",
    "count": "[length(parameters('someParam'))]",
    "input": {
    "name": "[concat('OtherProbe', parameters('someParam')[copyindex('probes')])]",
    "properties": {
        "intervalInSeconds": 5,
        "numberOfProbes": 2,
        "port": "[parameters('someParam')[copyindex('probes')]]",
        "protocol": "Tcp"
    }
    }
}
]
```

So in this case I need first two probes (FirstProbe and SecondProbe) to be explicitly defined but also I need more probes to be added based on someParam array values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to do this:

```
"variables": {
    "probes-static": [
        {
            "name": "FirstProbe",
            "properties": {
                "intervalInSeconds": 5,
                "numberOfProbes": 2,
                "port": 123,
                "protocol": "Tcp"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "SecondProbe",
            "properties": {
                "intervalInSeconds": 5,
                "numberOfProbes": 2,
                "port": 456,
                "protocol": "Tcp"
            }
        }
    ],
    "copy": [
        {
            "name": "probes-loop",
            "count": "[length(parameters('someParam'))]",
            "input": {
            "name": "[concat('OtherProbe', parameters('someParam')[copyindex('probes')])]",
                "properties": {
                    "intervalInSeconds": 5,
                    "numberOfProbes": 2,
                    "port": "[parameters('someParam')[copyindex('probes')]]",
                    "protocol": "Tcp"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "probes": "[concat(variables('probes-static'), variables('probes-loop'))]"
}
```

and then you can use `variable('probes')` as the result and assign it to the LB property

Comment: Thanks! (though I hoped to avoid messing with variables).Finally I've introduced only one new variable with two properties: one for static probes and second with copied values. And when using them in final resource I join both with union.